# How do i get json data to php

Tags: php, json

i need to get 'name' 'avl_bikes' and 'coordinates' to show up to my php from this website http://data.foli.fi/citybike/smoove. My code currently looks like this

```
<?php
@ini_set("display_errors", 1);
@ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

$string = file_get_contents("http://data.foli.fi/citybike/smoove");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);


$aika = $json_a["name"]["avl_bikes"];

echo $aika;


?>
```

Thank you

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Side Note: `$json_a["name"]["avl_bikes"];` should produce Undefined index notice.
`var_dump($json_a)` gives a pretty good idea about the structure of the `$json_a` array and it's pretty comlex. The `$json_a["name"]` does not exit, however a `$json_a["result"]` exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can access json decoded data as follows:-

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://data.foli.fi/citybike/smoove");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);

foreach($json_a['result'] as $key => $res){

    echo "avl_bikes = ".$res['avl_bikes']."<br>";
    echo "Name = ".$res['name']."<br>";
    echo "Coordinates = ".$res['coordinates']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: It's a valid answer, however I feel a little more explanation on why does this code work is welcome. I am not saying it doesn't, but for a beginner it's not that obvious why exactly this works and his code did not. Also `$key` is unused, you don't actually need it there.